# Inc., or Inc. in address

Tags: sentence

which is correct to use a comma or not after Inc., when the sentence breaks after the word "Inc."?
John Company, Inc.,
Princeton, NJ
or
John Company, Inc.
Princeton, NJ

Answer (score 1):

If you are not writing the address in “envelope format” (name, address, city-region-postcode on separate lines) you should include a comma wherever “envelope format” would have a line break. Thus, in your example, you should include a comma after “Inc.”.